# Does restricting guard node choice negatively affect anonymity?

Tags: configuration, guard-node

In response to the comment on https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0306-released-new-series-stable

> Is old version of tor node a bottleneck in the whole tor chain (in
>   sense of security)? Does it downgrade encryption also between other
>   nodes in the chain? If my guard uses old tor crypto which knows
>   nothing about ECC for encryption, does it mean that ECC will not be
>   used in my tor chain at all? (AFAIK, not, am I right?) Does it have
>   sense to restrict the choice of guard nodes only by those which run
>   last stable Tor release?

On May 2nd, 2017 yawning said:

> > If my guard uses old tor crypto which knows nothing about ECC for encryption, does it mean that ECC will not be used in my tor chain at
> >     all?
>
> So something that predates 0.2.4.something? It's done on a per hop
>   basis anyway.
>
> > **Does it have sense to restrict the choice of guard nodes only by those which run last stable Tor release?**
>
> **If you want to dramatically reduce your anonymity set, then sure.**

My question is:

Does restricting the guard nodes Tor chooses actually have a negative effect on anonymity?

Since a Tor user usually connects to the same guard node using a non-anonymous IP address, it seems this should have little effect on anonymity.

Comment: Over time a clever adversary may be able to build a model of which types of guards you're preferring and it would be easier for them to influence the reduced set of guards that fit your restrictions than the set of all possible guards.